# Order CSV Export - what fields does it export?

Tags: orders, export, csv

I am exporting orders Sales > Orders to CSV.

The problem is, I can't see which fields are actually exported.

If anyone has any insight, I would much appreciate it.

[image: Order CSV Export]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown you're using is from a custom or a 3rd party module. There is no way for us to tell you what fields are exported, however, you could just export it and find out.

**There is another way:**

The button just above that dropdown that says "Export" will **also** export a CSV for the current rendered view. To find out what fields would be exported for Sales Orders, we take a peek in the grid block for sales order controller in Adminhtml:

```
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'orders.csv';
    $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

So it looks like it exports columns based on the adminhtml/sales_order_grid block. The columns defined there happen to be the same as in that current view.

**Conclusion:**

If you were to use the orange Export button just above the dropdown you will receive a CSV export that is formatted similarly to the actual grid view. Using any other module or 3rd party to export will yield unpredictable (unknowable) results for this forum's audience.